# Website displays different page titles in certain browsers

Tags: page-title

There is a website which displays different page titles in certain browsers. If i open it in Chrome(latest Win10), then the page title is "Do they know it's Europe?", but if i open it in Chrome(latest Android, OnePlus 5), then it says "Do you know Italy's?". It seems every other browser (Opera, Edge, Mozilla, Mozilla for Andriod, etc) shows the first title. I checked the source code of the pages, but they seem to be identical to me.

Here it is what i can see when i open that page in Chrome for Android: https://prnt.sc/nrkq26

And here it is what i can see opening that page on PC:
http://prntscr.com/nrku2n

http://dotheyknowitseurope.eu/index.html

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: Hey, I'm not sure what the problem per se is to answer here but I thought I should add that web servers can actually detect what device and what browser you are using to access a site and can change their content accordingly.

Most providers will do this to provide a webpage that performs as best as possible on a device (e.g. a smaller scale mobile friendly view for tablets and mobile devices) however in your case it seems like they are actually changing the content based on what browser you are using.

Hope this helps -James